# Вводится дата в строку и надо проверить не прошли ли сроки годности

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль, время

Пишу функцию, которая проверяет купоны на работоспособность. Не могу нормально сравнить дату купона нужно, чтобы первая была меньше второй:

Весь код:

```
def check_coupon(entered_code, correct_code, current_date, expiration_date):

value = False

entered_code = str (entered_code)
correct_code = str (correct_code)

print (   current_date.replace (",", "").split ())
print (expiration_date.replace (",", "").split ())

months = {
    1  : "January"  ,
    2  : "February" ,
    3  : "March"    ,
    4  : "April"    ,
    5  : "May"      ,
    6  : "June"     ,
    7  : "July"     ,
    8  : "August"   ,
    9  : "September",
    10 : "October"  ,
    11 : "November" ,
    12 : "December" 
    }


if  entered_code == correct_code:

    splitted_current_date    =    current_date.replace (",", "").split ()
    splitted_expiration_date = expiration_date.replace (",", "").split ()

    i = 1

    while i <= 12:
        if months [i] == splitted_current_date    [0]:    current_month = i

        if months [i] == splitted_expiration_date [0]: expiration_month = i

        i += 1

    print (current_month   )
    print (expiration_month)

    current_day     = int (splitted_current_date    [1])
    expiration_day  = int (splitted_expiration_date [1])

    current_year    = int (splitted_current_date    [2])
    expiration_year = int (splitted_expiration_date [2])

    print (current_day)
    print (expiration_day)
    print (current_year)
    print (expiration_year)

    if current_year <= expiration_year:
        if current_month <= expiration_month:
            if current_day <= expiration_day:
                value = True

    else:
        value = False


else:
    value = False


return value
```

Вот так тестил работоспособность кода:

```
print (check_coupon ('123','123','September 5, 2014','October 1, 2014'), True)
print (check_coupon ('123a','123','September 5, 2014','October 1, 2014'), False)

print (check_coupon ("123", "123", "July 9, 2015", "July 9, 2015"), "==", True) 
print (check_coupon ("123", "123", "July 9, 2015", "July 2, 2015"), "==", False)
```

Проблема в этом куске кода:

```
if current_year <= expiration_year:
        if current_month <= expiration_month:
            if current_day <= expiration_day:
                value = True
```

Пробовал еще вот так:

```
if current_year <= expiration_year and current_month <= expiration_month and current_day <= expiration_day:
    value = True
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все можно значительно упростить:

```
from datetime import datetime

def check_coupon(entered_code, correct_code, current_date, expiration_date):
    
    current = datetime.strptime(current_date, '%B %d, %Y')    
    expiration = datetime.strptime(expiration_date, '%B %d, %Y')

    return entered_code == correct_code and current <= expiration


print(check_coupon(123, 123, 'September 5, 2014','October 1, 2014'))
print(check_coupon(123, 123, "July 9, 2015","July 2, 2015"))
```

Вывод:

```
True
False
```

**UPDATE**

Вот для примера, как можно преобразовывать из строки в дату:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_str1 = 'Monday, December 7, 2020'
date_str2 = '7/12/20'
date_str3 = '7-12-2018'

date_dt1 = datetime.strptime(date_str1, '%A, %B %d, %Y')
date_dt2 = datetime.strptime(date_str2, '%d/%m/%y')
date_dt3 = datetime.strptime(date_str3, '%d-%m-%Y')

print(date_dt1)
print(date_dt2)
print(date_dt3)
```

Вывод:

```
2020-12-07 00:00:00
2020-12-07 00:00:00
2018-12-07 00:00:00
```

Comment: Блин, похоже я не умею гуглить. Хотя и ранее знал об этом модуле, но почему-то не думал, что там так удобно можно передать строковые значения в дату. Искал как раз то, о чем вы написали.

Comment: @Diareich  это бывает))) Удачи в решении задачи

Comment: осталось небольшая проблема у меня почему, то не работает код, при таких параметрах (0, False, "September 5, 2014","September 25, 2014"), а если ставлю принудительно вывод через строковое значение, то выводит при этих параметрах ошибку ("a12v564", "a12v564", 'March 5, 1998', 'March 25, 1998'). Это очень странно.

Comment: @Diareich Проверьте код - у меня при  (0, False, "September 5, 2014","September 25, 2014")  и при ("a12v564", "a12v564", 'March 5, 1998', 'March 25, 1998') выдает True. Учитывайте что 0 и False логически равны

Comment: Мне надо было, чтобы 0 и False были не равны и оценивались, как строка, но я уже разобрался.

Answer (score 1):

Условие должно быть сильно сложнее, чем то, которое вы написали. Что-то типа вот такого на псевдоязыке:

```
год1 < год2 или (год1 == год2 и месяц1 < месяц2) или (год1 == год2 и месяц1 == месяц2 и день1 <= день2)
```

Наверное, проще посчитать через некое примерное "число дней от начала эпохи" для каждой из дат и потом сравнить уже эти числа между собой:

```
число_дней = год * 356 + месяц * 31 + день

число_дней1 <= число_дней2
```